# Copy files to another directory with random numeric name

Tags: batch-file

I need help from you. I tried copying several files to a folder with random numeric names, Example:

```
xcopy /Y .\*.* .\new\%random%%random%%random%.*
```

than I get this output:

```
.\error2.exe
.\icon_error.ico
.\icon_static.ico
.\opsec.exe
.\static2.EXE
5 File(s) copied
```

and when I do `dir /B` command to the `new`  directory, I get this:

```
6263226566221.exe
6263226566221.ico
```

So basically 3 files are missing, I tried running it again without `/Y` parameter and it asked me `Do you want to overwrite the existing file?`.
How do I skip this problem, I need a simple, lightweight solution to fix this!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This batch file will xcopy every file from current folder to `.\new` excluding itself.
The new name will be a random number of specified constant length (stuffed with leading zeroes if necessary)

```
@Echo off&SetLocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
Set Nulls=00000000000000000000
Set Len=10
For %%A in (*) Do (
  Set Num=%Nulls%!Random!!Random!!Random!!Random!
  Echo xcopy /Y "%%A" ".\new\!Num:~-%Len%!%%~xA"
)
Pause
```

If the output look OK remove the echo in front of xcopy.

Comment: Thanks! This helped me a lot! +1